# Finding the center of an kissing circle

Tags: graphing-functions

I have three circles in the following graph:

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDGNe.png)

What I want to do is get the upper circle to touch the other two circles, like so:

[Touching Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjTda.png)

What is the graph equation for what I'm looking for (red circle)?

Comment: By left-right symmetry, the center $(x_c,y_c)$ is of the form $(o, y_c)$ such that the distance from this center to either of the other centers is 2.0.  Solve for $y_c$.  Then the circle has equation:  $x^2 + (y-y_c)^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2 + \left(y - \left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)\right)^2 = 1$$